# Anyway to debug all the cells of a Jupyter Notebook in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, vscode-debugger

My teacher keep giving me Jupyter Notebook where the entire program is split to different cell for each class. The last cell, is the bootstrap code, creating an instance of the ~main class and calling a method on it.

I used Jupyter Notebook inside VS Code because the real Jupyter Notebook on a browser seems to be worst about debugging and code completion...

I don't find a way in VS Code to ask to debug the entire code, so that the code stop to any breakpoint set. The only workaround I found is to merge all the cells...

Without merging all the cells, if I debug the last cell with the bootstrap code, it will complain it doesn't find the class(es) because in different cell(s)...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a way to do this at the time of this writing. The feature to run all cells is part of VS Code (`Notebook: Run All`), and the feature to debug a cell seems to be part of the Jupyter extension (`Jupyter: Debug Cell`).

Googling "`site:github.com vscode notebook OR jupyter issues debug all cells`" turns up nothing of interest in the first page of results. I think you should raise a new feature request issue ticket. I'm not sure where best, but I'd try the Jupyter extension's repo: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/new?assignees=&labels=feature-request&projects=&template=3_feature_request.md.

Comment: If anyone reading this ends up raising an issue ticket like I suggested, please either comment here with the link to it, or notify me in it with "@starball5" and a link to this Stack Overflow post so I can update it.